Number of continuous derivatives of $\mathrm{rect}(x)$
I am learning about functions with finite continuous derivatives, i.e. functions of the class $C^k$. An example of such a function is given on Wikipedia, where it is said that for each even integer $k$ the function $$f(x)=|x|^{k+1}\in C^k, \quad \forall x\in\mathbb{R}.$$ I am having trouble identifying when a function has a finite number of continuous derivatives. For example, consider the rectangle function defined by
$$
\mathrm{rect}(x)=\begin{cases} 0 & |t|>1/2, \\
                               1/2 & |t|=1/2, \\
                               1 & |t|<1/2.
\end{cases}
$$
This function appears to be discontinuous, and so there is no $k$ such that $\mathrm{rect}(x)\in C^k$. Is this correct?

Yes. That is correct, rect$(x)$ is not even $C^0$ since it is discontinuous. In general $C^k$ means the all first $k$ derivatives, including the zeroeth derivative (the function itself), are continuous.

Is there a similar function that is $C^0$?

A trapezoid function made of connected line segments would be $C^0$ and not $C^1$.

Yes the triangle function is also an example because it is continuous
